# writing apache2 htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I think my question is not clear enough, i will rewrite it.

I want to echo my url from my index.php, it didnt work for me so i included the php code. if it help i have include .htaccess file.thanks

```
Notice: Undefined index: url in /var/www/mvc/index.php on line 3

<?php

$url = isset($_GET['url']);

echo $url;

?>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: How are you going to send a GET parameter to the htaccess file?? From what I know this file is used by the server without any interaction from the client-side.

Comment: it seems his first snippet is index.php and the second one is the htaccess rules trying to rewrite to the first

Comment: this works fine in my configuration (prints `1` as expected)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't relate to your htaccess file, it simply states that the get param has no index with that name.

Try dumping out your $_GET to see its contents.

Answer (score 0):

isset returns a boolean.
So you need to wrap it in an if statement in case.

```
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : 'index';
echo $url;
```

Doing so will suppress the notice.

Comment: It is actually perfectly fine to assign a boolean value to a variable.

Comment: But $url would just be true/false. Pretty useless.

Comment: Hi Adrian thank you for your response but i want to echo what write on url how do i do that? thanks again